# Add "same" Entity to multiple Entities results in null

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Sorry for bad Title, I'll try and explain better here. For simplicity let us say that I have two Entities in my Code First Migration. One Player with and Id and a Name, and one Match with an Id, a winner and a looser. The winner and looser is a Player (not the same Player). What I want to have is that a single match can have one winner and one looser. I have the following DbContext:

```
public IDbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }
public IDbSet<Match> PlayerMatches { get; set; }
```

My Player class looks like this:

```
public int PlayerId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Match> Matches { get; set; }
```

My Match class:

```
public int MatchId { get; set; }
public Player Winner { get; set; }
public Player Looser { get; set; }
```

If I have the following code in my parsing, (the parsing is "correct" correct data is put in Db):

```
Player player1 = db.Players.Where(....); //Here I just select which is the correct player (OK)
Player player2 = db.Players.Where(....);
Match m = new Match();
m.Winner = player1;
m.Looser = player2;

player1.Matches.Add(m);
player2.Matches.Add(m);
db.SaveChanges();
```

If I inspect the Match before it is added to the two players everything is OK, and it adds without any errors. The problem comes when I inspect the Db or tries to retrieve a Match. Depending on the Player I am "using" I get null for the winner/looser depending on whether or not "my player" won/loose. If this player won the looser is null vice versa... I believe I'm missing som mapping or so but I can't understand which, I am very new to Code First and this is the first db problem I have encountered in my application.

Any ideas?

Ciao!

Comment: Sorry for taking up anyones time, I had missed the "virtual" keyword befor the Looser and Winner properties in the Match class... Working fine now. Long day...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else is having a long day and find themselves facing a similar issue, add "virtual" to the properties you need for the case. In my case Winner and Looser in the Match class.